# How do i get my UI components in Angular 8

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I am using my own created component. What `app-button.ts` does it that it check for current user roles and then renders if it match the define roles.

ButtonType is just to define what style to use.

demo.ts:

```
  <app-button
  buttonText="BACK"
  (clickEvent)="goBack()"
  [buttonType]="'secondary'"
  >
  </app-button>
```

app-button button implementation:

```
<button *ngIf="canRender" class="{{ buttonClass }}" (click)="onClickEvent()" [disabled]="disabled">
  <span class="{{ spanClass }}">{{ buttonText }}</span>
</button>
```

app-button.ts file:

```
export class PrimaryButtonComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() buttonText: string;
  @Input() disabled? = false;
  @Input() allowedRoles: Role[] = [];
  @Input() buttonType = 'primary';

  canRender? = false;

  buttonClass: string;
  spanClass: string;

  @Output() clickEvent = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private credentialsService: CredentialsService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.allowedRoles.length !== 0) {
      const currentUserRoles: Role[] = this.credentialsService.currentUserValue.role.slice();

      this.canRender = allowedToAccess(this.allowedRoles, currentUserRoles);
    } else {
      this.canRender = true;
    }

    if (this.buttonType === 'primary') {
      this.buttonClass = 'primary-button';
      this.spanClass = 'primary-button-text';
    }

    if (this.buttonType === 'secondary') {
      this.buttonClass = 'secondary-button';
      this.spanClass = 'secondary-button-text';
    }
  }

  onClickEvent() {
    this.clickEvent.emit();
  }
}
```

Unit Test:

```
fit('should navigate back to dashboard when click back button', async(() => {
    const onClickSpy = spyOn(component, 'goBack').and.callThrough();
    const routerSpy = spyOn(router, 'navigate');

    // Click Back button
    const button = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.secondary-button'));

    expect(button).not.toBeNull();
  }));
```

when i am doing my unit test, I am seeing this error

```
Error: Expected null not to be null.
```

But my actual UI is showing the component. how can it be null in test?

Comment: what's `buttonClass` ?

Comment: variable to set my class style sheet

Comment: that's obvious, but show the code how it's set because it's pretty important info here don't you think?

Comment: I added the code implementation for the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `TestBed.configureTestingModule`, in the `declarations` array, add `ButtonComponent` (assuming `ButtonComponent` is what it is called as the class). After doing this, `expect(button).not.toBeNull();` should be good to go.

Comment: I had that component in a shared module and it was in the shared module under the declaration.

Comment: Just a side note: Importing huge modules into your tests will slow down the test execution. (You'll notice this when there is  lots of tests written )